# How to build a long-running, partially-asynchronous service with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'll preface this with the fact that I'm pretty new to Spring. But what I'm trying to do is create a service `MyService` that pulls jobs from another external service `SomeService` via REST calls periodically on a single thread, and then dispatches them to another "thing", call it `JobRunner`, which takes each job and does something with it. I would like `JobRunner` to be asynchronous, but I'm not sure what the most correct way would be to do this in Spring. Coming from the non-IoC world, the flow would look something like this (Go syntax):

```
for {
    job, err := getJobFromSomeService()

    if job != nil {
        go runJob(job)
    }
}
```

What would the layout look like for something like this in Spring? I'm thinking about having some sort of @Scheduled `Poller` component to pull jobs on some interval, but then I'm not sure how to access these jobs in the `JobRunner` component. Maybe add some sort of thread-safe `Queue` bean and wire that into both `Poller` and `JobRunner` as sort of a shared-memory solution? But then I'm not sure if that's a good practice in Spring etc, or even how to properly set that up via Spring.

I'm basically looking for suggestions about the proper way to tackle a design problem using Spring Boot as opposed to a non-"Inversion-of-control" solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things to consider:

1. schedule a job that calls other service(with http client library, like [resttemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template))
2. run job in another thread(with thread pool)

In my opinion, you can try something like below:

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
private ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
public void runJobs() {

    HttpHeaders headers2 = new HttpHeaders();
    headers2.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers2.set("Host", "api.xxx.com");
    headers2.set("Accept", "*/*");
    headers2.set("Authorization", "");
    String requestBody = "some request body";
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers2);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://api.xxx.com/xxx", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.getBody());

    JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");

    JSONArray jsonArray = data.getJSONArray("listJobs");
    for (Object o : jsonArray) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            runOneJob(o);
        }, threadPoolExecutor);
        future.whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> {
            if (throwable != null) {
                log.error("runOneJob error", throwable);
            }
        });
    }

}

private void runOneJob(Object o) {
    // do something
}
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(1024);
    poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(128);

    HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    httpClientBuilder.setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager);

    clientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClientBuilder.build());
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(100);
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(5000);

    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
}

@Bean
public ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor() {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            10,
            100,
            2L,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(300),
            Executors.defaultThreadFactory(),
            new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy()
    );
}
```